# And/or conditional filtering with single factor levels that meet multiple conditions

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, group-by, conditional-statements

Consider this data frame:

```r
data <- data.frame(ID = rep(letters[1:4], each= 4),
                   Year = c('1990','1990','1990','1990',
                            '1990','1990','2000', '2000',
                            '1990','1990','1990','1990',
                            '1990','1990','2000', '2000'))
```

We have 4 unique `ID`'s and 2 `Year`s. `ID == a` and `ID == c` only have observations in 1990, while `ID == b` and `ID == D` have observations for both years. We want to filter cases where an `ID` has observations for both years, so the expected result would look like this:

```
ID   Year
b    1990
b    1990
b    2000
b    2000
d    1990
d    1990
d    2000
d    2000
```

Using `dplyr`s syntax, we cant `group_by(ID)` and `filter` using `&` like this:

```r
data%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  filter(Year == '1990' & Year == '2000')
```

because both conditions relate levels of the same factor (`Year`).

So how can we do this using `dplyr`s syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can do it in this way;

```
data %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(unique_ind=n_distinct(Year)) %>%
filter(unique_ind==2) %>%
ungroup %>%
select(-unique_ind)
```

**output;**

```
 ID    Year 

1 b     1990 
2 b     1990 
3 b     2000 
4 b     2000 
5 d     1990 
6 d     1990 
7 d     2000 
8 d     2000
```

Answer (score 0):

We could construct the logical vector in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(Year) > 1) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  ID    Year 
  <chr> <chr>
1 b     1990 
2 b     1990 
3 b     2000 
4 b     2000 
5 d     1990 
6 d     1990 
7 d     2000 
8 d     2000
```